# Problems with #define in c

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define M(x) x - x

int main () {
    printf ("%d %d\n",M(M (1+2)) , M(M (3)));
    return 0;
}
```

Can someone explain to me step by step how the result to this is `6 -6`?

Comment: Write down exactly what the macro expands to, on a piece of paper. Make no assumptions. The definition should be `#define M(x) ((x) - (x))`

Answer (score 2):

What has to be clear in order to understand what's going on is that when macros are resolved it is just a replacement, not a calculation.

For example

```
M(1+2)
```

is substituted with

```
1 + 2 - 1 + 2
^     ^ ^
x     - x
```

It is important to observe that the minus is not applied to the full expression. So in this case the result would be `4`.

Let's analyze our composed macros:

```
/* First step */
M(M(1+2)                              M(M(3))
M(1 + 2 - 1 + 2)                      M(3 - 3)
  ^     ^ ^                             ^ ^ ^
  x     - x                             x - x

/* Second step */
M(1 + 2 - 1 + 2)                      M(3 - 3)
1 + 2 - 1 + 2 - 1 + 2 - 1 + 2         3 - 3 - 3 - 3
^             ^ ^                     ^     ^ ^
x             - x                     x     - x
```

These strange sums are passed to the compiler that finally simplifies them. And the results are actually `6` (on the left) and `-6` (on the right).

---

I guess that this result puzzled you because, with a define `x-x`, you expected to get 0 for each value of x. As I showed you, the reason why you didn't get it is that the minus sign applies only to the first addend. In order to get the *"always zero macro"*, just use parenthesis:

```
#define M(x) (x)-(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

`M(1+2)` is replaced with `1+2 -1+2`.

`M(1+2 -1+2)` is replaced with `1+2 -1+2 - 1+2 -1+2`.

This is `1+2-1+2-1+2-1+2`, which is evaluated:

- `3-1+2-1+2-1+2`
- `2+2-1+2-1+2`
- `4-1+2-1+2`
- `3+2-1+2`
- `5-1+2`
- `4+2`
- `6`

I expect this gives you the knowledge to figure out `M(M(3))`.